# Why do Firefox setInterval callback arguments differ from other browsers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, setinterval

I tested this script in every browser on Win 7. It doesn't work on Firefox only (ver. 3.6.13).

The alert box returns "undefined" in all the browsers except for Firefox that returns a random number. Here is the script

```
function nextSlide(nav){
    alert(nav);
}

jQuery(function(){
    var set = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000); 
});
```

Here is a [live demo](http://creativotheme.com/test-setinterval.php)

Answer (score 5):

The extra argument is the number of milliseconds that the callback was late. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval):

> #### Callback arguments
>
> setInterval() will pass the number of milliseconds late the callback was called into the callback function, which can confuse it if it expects something else as an argument. To sidestep that problem, use an anonymous function to call your callback.

The fix is to write this instead:

```
var set = setInterval(function() { nextSlide(); }, 2000);
```

Comment: If your function is expecting parameters you should pass them as additional parameters to setInterval as per the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Byers is correct in explaining it with the Mozilla documentation.

However, **this is a Firefox extension**. The [WindowTimers interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#timers) -- at least as it is in HTML5 *working draft* -- actually has a different requirement. Of course, since this is a volatile domain...

> > handle = window . setInterval( handler [, timeout [, arguments ] ] )
> >
> > Schedules a timeout to run handler every timeout milliseconds. *Any arguments are passed straight through to the handler*.

Therefore, Firefox could be seen in violation of this as `arguments.length` is 1 even though "no arguments" were passed.

I believe for HTML4 it's just defacto implementations without any "official standards" defined -- or at least none that I know of -- and, in which case, Firefox can do pretty much whatever it pleases. I would be happy for a correction/reference.

**Edit:**

Firefox *does* support the argument pass-through, as noted by Neil and `arguments.length` is always one more than the number of arguments passed to account for the "offset" data -- no magic is being done on `arguments.length` (which would be really scary in and of itself).

This is important to keep in mind: don't use and/or be careful when using `arguments.length` inside a timer callback or face browser differences. (This is inline with other event callbacks).

Comment: Firefox supports this too. The additional lateness parameter simply gets appended to the list of additional arguments.

Comment: Whoa! Is that a randomly-generated gravatar?